# The difference in use Repository or RepositoryInterface to load model

Tags: magento2, api, repository, service-contract

I found two ways to load model on net by **service contracts** in Magento 2. One is use the **Repository**, another is using the **RepositoryInterface** directly. Both work well.

What is the **difference** between the two ways? **Which is better**?

Why **RepositoryInterface** could be used **directly** and work? **RepositoryInterface** is just a API and no content in the method, I didn't set a di.xml for it too.

### Example for using Repository

```
...
protected $productRepository; 
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function loadMyProduct($sku)
{
    return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
}
...
```

### Example for using RepositoryInterface

```
...
protected $productRepository; 
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function loadMyProduct($sku)
{
    return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the core. The class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` implements interface `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`. So basically, you can use the function `get($sku)` of both. The difference is the `ProductRepositoryInterface` usually use with the API as you see. If you don't use the API, use the `ProductRepository`.

The `ProductRepositoryInterface` with no content in the method so you can find it in `var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface`. Magento will auto generate the code.

There are what I find out! Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

All will run into Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository only because we have this line

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" />
```

in `ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml`